# Referencing a dll in Java

Tags: java, c++, vb.net

I need to reference a C++ dll from my Java project.  The method that I need to expose is actually written in Visual Basic.  Is there any way to access the Visual Basic code in C++, so that it can eventually be accessed in the Java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jmac posted the original question on my behalf.  I needed to find a way to call VB DLL function from a C++ DLL.

I've given up on the VB DLL and opted for a C# DLL.  The following link provides a downloadable Visual Studio solution that provides a project called DLLExporter that exports C# functions thus making them available to C++.  The VS solution was written in a version earlier than 2010 but the VS 2010 migrator had no problem importing it.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DllExporter.aspx

It solved my problem.

For the record, I tried to wrap my VB DLL inside the C# DLL but it didn't work.  So I just migrated my VB code to C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OS native DLLs from your Java project using [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface):

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is VB 6.0 and not VB.NET, you need to create an MFC DLL wrapper for your VB ActiveX DLL.

Here's more information on [Exporting VB DLL Functions](http://awc.al-williams.com/tips/tip30.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [JNI (Java Native Interface)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) technology.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [Java JNI Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html).

Answer (score 0):

as per Andriy Sholokh ,u need to use [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) to communicate with c or c++ from your java project. You have to use native method inside your java code. hope it will help you.